# Jersey not posting json

Tags: java, json, web-services, jersey

I'm attempting to post json to a remote php app using jersey. The php app doesn't seem to be receiving the post. When I view the header it appears to be there. Would anybody happen to know what I might be doing wrong?

Java Jersey Code

```
    String url = "http://support.mydomain.co/remoteapi/mydomain/index.php";

    WebResource webResource = client.resource(url);
    webResource.queryParam("action", Constant.CREATE_TICKET.name());

    Company company = companyDAO.findCompanyById(1);

    client.addFilter(new LoggingFilter(System.out));

    ClientResponse response = webResource.accept("application/json")
            .entity(company, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .post(ClientResponse.class);

    if (response.getStatus() != 200) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                + response.getStatus());
    }

    String output = response.getEntity(String.class);
```

Header

```
1 * Client out-bound request
1 > POST http://support.mydomain.co/remoteapi/mydomain/index.php?action=CREATE_TICKET
1 > Accept: application/json
1 > Content-Type: application/json
{"name":"Test Company","phones":[],"street1":null,"street2":null,"city":null,"stateName":{"name":"Florida"},"companyCategory":{"name":"hotel"},"zip":"12095","accountNumber":"00000002"}
1 * Client in-bound response
1 < 200
1 < Date: Wed, 13 Mar 2013 22:51:06 GMT
1 < Transfer-Encoding: chunked
1 < Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
1 < Connection: Keep-Alive
1 < Content-Type: application/json
1 < Server: Apache/2.2.23 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.23 OpenSSL/0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 mod_mono/2.6.3 mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635
1 < X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.17
1 <
```

PHP

```
print_r($_REQUEST);
```

Comment: According to your log output, the POST is successful, you're getting a `200` code and response headers from PHP, so I would suspect the issue might be with the server setup.

Comment: Did you check the WS call with another tool, example RestClient plugin for Firefox and see what would be the reponse for the same object

Comment: @Beny23 could you elaborate a bit more on "server setup"? Are you referring to the PHP server? If so, what would you recommend doing?

Comment: I'm no expert on PHP, all I'm saying is that according to the log info, the problem is more likely on the PHP end than Java client as the log shows that a POST is made and the response is received, just that the response is empty.  I would check the server logs, and add some debugging statements to your PHP code.